# how to convert object to complicated array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```
const data = {offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", offer_6: "5", note_6: "note"}
```

if I have to convert to an array of object As follows how can do?

```
const body = [
              {
                id: 4,// after underline is id
                is_disable: //value of offer_4 === undefined ? false : true,
                price: //value of offer_4,
                note: //value of note_4,
              },
              {
                id: 6,// after underline is id
                is_disable: //value of offer_6 === undefined ? false : true,
                price: //value of offer_6,
                note: //value of note_6,
              },
            ];
```

we have key like offer_4, number offer "_"  is an id so when I have key note_4 and offer_4 these value of them, must be in one object
if offer has a value then is_disabled must be true value otherwise must be false offer and note are always together
I hope my explanation is clear,

Comment: where is the correlation between them?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Show what you've tried.

Comment: @Alex we have key like offer_4, number offer "_" is a id so when I have key note_4 and offer_4 these value of them, must be in one object

Comment: @mplungjan I test all anser and that is better then the other so,I test again all answer tank you

Comment: Please add a complete example with and without offers

Comment: @mplungjan if offer has a value then is_disabled must be true value otherwise must be false
offer and note  are always together

Comment: That was not obvious. Please post input that shows BOTH examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const data = {offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", offer_6: "5", note_6: "note", note_7: "note"}
   

const reduced = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc,val) =>{
 const id = val.split('_')[1];
 if (acc[id]) return acc;
 acc[id] = {
    id, is_disabled: data[`offer_${id}`] === undefined, price: data[`offer_${id}`] || 0, note: data[`note_${id}`]
 }
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(reduced))
```

Comment: Is it because of the undefined value ??

Comment: The if statement prevents it from been updated

Comment: I mean, if the input object one day had `description_4` then you would have to update your code. Anyway it is a good answer for the specific question

Answer (score 2):

here is what you need to do :

```js
const data = { offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", offer_6: "5", note_6: "note", note_7: "note"}
   

const resultArray = [];
for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
  if (key.includes("offer")) {
    const _id = key.split("_")[1];
    const newItem = {
      id: _id, 
      is_disable: data[key] === undefined,
      price: data[key],
      note: data[`note_${_id}`], 
    };
    resultArray.push(newItem);
  }
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls, note that each `note` combines with `offer` will become an object. Otherwise, It's not.

```
if (acc[id]  
        || (splitValues[0] === "offer" && data[`note_${id}`] === undefined)
        || (splitValues[0] === "note" && data[`offer_${id}`] === undefined)) return acc;
```

```js
const data = {offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", offer_6: "5", note_6: "note", note_7: "note"}
   
const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>{
 const splitValues = key.split('_');
 const id = splitValues[1];
 if (acc[id]  
    || (splitValues[0] === "offer" && data[`note_${id}`] === undefined)
    || (splitValues[0] === "note" && data[`offer_${id}`] === undefined)) return acc;
    
 acc[id] = {
      id, 
      is_disabled: data[`offer_${id}`] !== undefined, 
      price: data[`offer_${id}`], 
      note: data[`note_${id}`]
   }
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: tnx for answering this part is_disabled: data[`offer_${id}`] !== undefined must be is_disabled: data[`offer_${id}`] === undefined, and for my situation offer and note are always together so dont need to condition fo check it

Answer (score 0):

I would try a reduce - note I handle the undefined offer in id 7

```js
const data = {
offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", 
offer_6: "5", note_6: "note" , 
note_7: "note"};
       
const body = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc,key) => {
  const [dataKey, dataId] = key.split("_");
  let obj = acc.find(({id}) => id===dataId)
  if (!obj) acc.push({id:dataId})
  obj = acc[acc.length-1];
  if (dataKey === "offer") {
    obj["price"] = data[key]
  }
  else obj[dataKey] = data[key]; // will add any new key too

  return acc
},[])
body.forEach(item => item["is_disable"]=!item["price"]);
console.log(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce with an object as accumulatroe and shape the value if you got the values.

```js
const
    data = { offer_4: "5", note_4: "note", offer_6: "5", note_6: "note" },
    result = Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        let [type, id] = k.split('_');
        id *= 1;
        type
        if (!r[id]) r[id] = { id, is_disable: false, price: undefined, note: undefined };
        if (type === 'offer' && v !== undefined) r[id].is_disable = true;
        if (type === 'offer') type = 'price';
        r[id][type] = v;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite extensive approach, and not that clean and short. But here we go:

```js
const data = {
  offer_4: "5",
  note_4: "note",
  offer_6: "5",
  note_6: "note"
};

let body = [];

function getByColumn(arr, col, val) {
  for (var elem of arr) {
    if (elem[col] === val) {
      return elem;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function removeElemByColumn(arr, col, val) {
  body = [];
  for (var elem of arr) {
    if (elem[col] !== val) {
      body.push(elem);
    }
  }
  return body;
}

for (var key in data) {
  let field = key.split('_')[0];
  let id = key.split('_')[1];
  let value = data[key];
  let is_disable = field === 'offer' && value > 0;
  let elem = getByColumn(body, 'id', id);

  if (elem) {
    elem[field] = value;
    elem.is_disable = elem.is_disable || is_disable;
    body = removeElemByColumn(body, 'id', id);
    body.push(elem);
  } else {
    elem = {};
    elem.id = id;
    elem[field] = value;
    elem.is_disable = is_disable;
    body.push(elem);
  }
}

console.log(body);
```